# psql always asking for credentials

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm unable to run any `psql` commands without it immediately prompting me for connection/login credentials. For example, `psql --help` or `psql --version` (full manual can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html)) immediately prompts me with:

```
temps-MacBook-Pro:local temp$ /usr/local/bin/psql --help
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
```

I've looked through the configuration files in default installation directory `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/` but can't really find anything that would force this prompt. Note that this was installed with the [EnterpriseDB installer](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) and everything seems to work properly when I connect to a DB.

Postgres 9.6 on OSX 10.11

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/psql` was a symlink for `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/scripts/runpsql.sh` which is EnterpriseDB's shell script wrapper around the actual actual binary which is `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql`.

I just needed to point `psql` to the real executable and not that shell script.